# angular custom component receives a reference to a field

Tags: angular

I tried to pass the input reference into my component but why is the `control` undefined?

```
<input #nameField="ngModel" />
<my-component [control]="nameField"></my-component>

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() control: FormControl;
    ngOnInit() {
        //this.control is undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: Does you parent component get it's data from a server? Meaning the call will be async, and before the data comes through the parent component have already send down undefined data. What is the data value for `nameField` in your parent component?

Comment: @AlfaBravo There is an `ngIf`in the parent tag to work around the async problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `ngModel`, working code like this -

```
<input #nameField />
<hello [control]="nameField"></hello>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/control?file=src/app/app.component.html)

PS: You need to use `@Input` in your child component in order to access.